# How do I pass props to nested route as I am having undefined in this.props.match

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-router

I have successfully implemented some nested routes to show different navbar depending on the component being rendered, but I am having a problem passing props through them.

Here is an example code of my routes.

```
<Route exact path="/admin/dashboard/update/:slug" render={() => <Dashboard><UpdateProperty /></Dashboard>} />

<Route exact path="/property/:slug" render={() => <Layout><SingleProperty /></Layout> } />
```

and here is where I pass the props through `Link component`

```
<Link to={`/admin/dashboard/update/${property.slug}`} >
<Link to={ `/property/${ slug }` } className="btn-primaryCustom room-link">view Details</Link>
```

I tried to destructure the slug like this.

```
const { slug } = this.props.match.params
```

but it gives me an error. `TypeError: Cannot read property 'params' of undefined`

The challenge is that I can see the slug in my browser menu but when I try to get it using `this.props.match.params` it throughs an error. I then logged `this.props.match` to the console and got `undefined`.

The code for the dashboard component is below:

```
// components
import DashboardNav from '../components/DashboardNav'

const Dashboard = ({ children }) => {

    return (
        <section className="">
            <div className="row">
                <div id="main" className="col-sm-12 d-flex">
                    <aside id="sidebar" className="dashboard col-md-2 bg-secondary">
                        <ul className="nav flex-column justify-content-center align-items-center">
                            <li className="nav-item py-md-4 px-md-3">
                                <Link className="nav-link active text-white" to="#">Logo</Link>
                            </li>
                            <li className="nav-item p-md-3">
                                <Link className="nav-link active text-white" to="#">Dashboard</Link>
                            </li>
                            <li className="nav-item p-md-3">
                                <Link className="nav-link text-white" to="#">All Properties</Link>
                            </li>
                            <li className="nav-item p-md-3">
                                <Link className="nav-link text-white" to="#">New Properties</Link>
                            </li>
                            <li className="nav-item p-md-3">
                                <Link className="nav-link text-white" to="#">Messages</Link>
                            </li>
                            <li className="nav-item p-md-3">
                                <Link className="nav-link text-white" to="#">About</Link>
                            </li>
                            <li className="nav-item p-md-3">
                                <Link className="nav-link text-white" to="#">Contact</Link>
                            </li>
                            <li className="nav-item p-md-3">
                                <Link className="nav-link text-white" to="#">Blog</Link>
                            </li>
                            <li className="nav-item p-md-3">
                                <Link className="nav-link text-white" to="#">Logout</Link>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </aside>

                    <article id="dashboard" className="col-sm-12 col-md-10">
                        <header id="menu" className="dashboard d-flex flex-column">
                            <DashboardNav />
                        </header>

                        <main className="py-md-3">

                            {/* { loading && <Loading /> } */}
                            { children }

                        </main>
                    </article>                        
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    )

}
```

And the Layout component is below:

```
import React from 'react';

// components
import Navbar from './Navbar'

const Layout = ({ children }) => {
    return (
        <>
            <Navbar />
            { children }
        </>
    );

}

export default Layout;
```

I do know there is a way to implement this but I can't seem to get the correct method yet.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use the withRouter HOC to access match inside your component

```
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
```

and then wrap your component export as

```
export default withRouter(Component)
```

Then you will get access to match prop.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to solve this by setting up my routes as follows:

```
<Route exact path="/admin/dashboard/update/:slug" render={(props) => <Dashboard><UpdateProperty { ...props } /></Dashboard>} />

<Route exact path="/property/:slug" render={(props) => <Layout><SingleProperty { ...props } /></Layout> } />
```

And this works.